# Limit of $\exp(z^2)$ as $|z|$ tends to infinity

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $g(z) = \exp(z^2)$ and $L$ a ray starting at the origin. Determine those $L$ along which $g$ has a limit (finite or infinite) as $|z|$ tends to infinity and $z ∈ L$. Find the value of the limit also. Please I need help.

Comment: Hint: $L$ can be parametrized by $z = re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ is fixed and $0 \le r < \infty$.

Comment: The limit is $0$ if $L$ is inside the "North" or "South" quadrants, $\infty$ if inside the "East" or "West" and doesn't exist if $L$ part of their boundary.

Comment: @A.S. That's not quite true. (It looks like you forgot the square.)

Comment: @mrf - indeed. corrected.

Comment: @A.S. The complex plane doesn't have a "north" quadrant. Its quadrants are "northeast" (Quadrant I), "northwest" (Quadrant II), "southwest" (Quadrant III) and "southeast" (Quadrant IV). Can you please make what you mean by "north," "south," "east," and "west" more specific?

Comment: @Noble If you can figure out what NW and NE quadrants are, deducing what N quadrant stands for is pretty easy. The name of the quadrant is derived from the direction of its bisector.

Comment: @A.S. There are two quadrants that I would classify as "north": Quadrants I and II. Likewise, there are two "south" quadrants, Quadrants III and IV, two "west" quadrants, Quadrants II and III, and two "east" quadrants, Quadrant I and IV. How am I supposed to know which is which?

Comment: @Noble The name of the quadrant is derived from the direction of its bisector. There is only one North quadrant. Quarants I and II are in the North half-plane but are not North quadrants.

Comment: Oh...are you splitting the complex plane into quadrants based off the lines containing $q+qi$ for $q \in \mathbb{R}$ and $q-qi$ for $q \in \mathbb{R}$? If so, I understand what you're talking about now.

Comment: HINT:  $$\begin{align}
\left|e^{z^2}\right|&=\left|e^{R^2\cos(2\phi)}e^{iR^2\sin(2\phi)}\right|\\\\
&=e^{R^2\cos(2\phi)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Noble Yes. I'm using quadrant as in the original "one quarter of a circle" sense which is more general than specific I,II,III,IV quadrants.